# Django Model is not printing the Model Details

Tags: python, django, model, admin

I am new to Django/python and I am helping the team in migrating Django project as the installed server needs to be migrated.

**Old Version**

Django - 1.6.5

Python - 2.7

Due to some compatibility and versions not available, below the versions which we migrated to and was able to bring up the application without any errors. There were some compilation error related to deprecated methods and was able to correct that.

**Migrated Version**

Django - Django-1.6.5

Python – 3.4

Database – sqllite

Pillow - Pillow-3.3.0

PIP - pip-1.5.4

Everything looks fine, except the admin module. In the main admin screen instead of displaying the module fields, it is just displaying the object name.

**Below the location model list it used to display before migration**

### *Location*

Room: A | Cabinet: 23 | Drawer: 7

Room: A | Cabinet: 24 | Drawer: 4

**After Migration, it just displays the location object name**

### *Location*

Location object

Location object

### **I looked at the model.py and below the location model defined**

**class Location(models.Model):

```
room = models.CharField(max_length=31, 
                        help_text='(Required) e.g. A, B, C, D, E, F')

station = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, 
                        blank=True,
                        null=True,
                        help_text='e.g. 1, 2, ...')

cabinet = models.IntegerField(blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              help_text='e.g. 1, 2, ...')

shelf = models.IntegerField(blank=True,
                            null=True,
                            help_text='e.g. 1, 2, ...')

drawer = models.IntegerField(blank=True,
                             null=True,
                             help_text='e.g. 1, 2, ...')

map = models.ImageField(upload_to='location_maps', 
                        blank=True,
                        null=True)

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('room', 'station', 'cabinet' ,'shelf', 'drawer'),)


def __unicode__(self):
    string = 'Room: {}'.format(self.room)
    if self.station:
        string += ' | Station: {}'.format(self.station)
    if self.cabinet:
        string += ' | Cabinet: {}'.format(self.cabinet)
    if self.shelf:
        string += ' | Shelf: {}'.format(self.shelf)
    if self.drawer:
        string += ' | Drawer: {}'.format(self.drawer)
    return string*
```

---

**Below the configuration for admin.py**

---

*from django.contrib import admin

from mgmt.models import *

admin.site.register(Location)*

---

Any help would be really appreciated as I am not seeing any code change in the admin.py to make any correction

**Below the Table**

*CREATE TABLE "mgmt_location" (

```
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

"room" varchar(31) NOT NULL,

"station" integer,

"cabinet" integer,

"shelf" integer,

"drawer" integer,

"map" varchar(100),

UNIQUE ("room", "station", "cabinet", "shelf", "drawer")
```

)*

Comment: Update: When I tried with below code in the model.py, it is displaying the names.    def __str__(self):
         return self.id. But then it started giving below error when we tried to edit the items or click on to display the edit admin screen           TypeError at /admin/mgmt/equipment/S040942/
__str__ returned non-string (type Item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing `def __unicode__():` with `def __str__():` as

in Python 2, `def __unicode__():` had been used to determine the human-readable representation of an object.But in Python 3, it's has been replaced with `def __str__():`

Comment: sorry, forget to say. Please also change the last line <code> return string* <code> to this <code> return self.string <code> as it's a class variable. if it's still give the same error try typecasting this string like <code> return str(self.string) <code>

Comment: Thanks Again Muhammad. In each model, there are different data types, files, lists, date etc. So in the return, should i convert each fields? Current code is returning only the id. So when I use as below it still gives error ->     def __str__(self):

        return str(self.id)

Comment: or do I need to do any modifications in admin.py. My admin.py just looks as admin.site.register(InventoryUser)
admin.site.register(Tooling)
admin.site.register(Location)
admin.site.register(Equipment)
admin.site.register(DvtSample)

Comment: hi Dais, i have tried with `return str(self.id)` and it's working fine. 
First of all `__str__()` must always return a String and you shouldn't return a List or Dict in `__str__()`. As Admin expecting a single String attribute. So, instead of returning a List you can return concatenate String and it'll be working fine.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, it started working. Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Muhammad, I have tried that, then the templates started giving error.

For example I am getting different errors in different templates like below. I have different models and all different models started giving one or the other error related to non-string(type Item), in the edit screen

**Error 1 - When I click on the history**

***str** returned non-string (type Item)
Request Method:
GET 
Request URL:
http://10.20.130.91:8000/admin/mgmt/equipment/S040942/history/ 
Django Version:
1.6.5 
Exception Type:
TypeError 
Exception Value:
**str** returned non-string (type Item)

Exception Location:
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py in force_text, line 106*

**Error 2, when I click on edit**

*TypeError at /admin/mgmt/tooling/PRO102937/
**str** returned non-string (type Item)
Request Method:
GET 
Request URL:
http://10.20.130.91:8000/admin/mgmt/tooling/PRO102937/ 
Django Version:
1.6.5 
Exception Type:
TypeError 
Exception Value:
**str** returned non-string (type Item)

Exception Location:
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py in force_text, line 106*